# Changing the content type for a list will keep the old content type's columns inside the list

Tags: 2013, development, content-type, site-column

I have created a new Issue tracking list inside my Team site inside SP2013. then i removed the Issue content type from the list and i added the Event content type instead. but currently the list columns will keep showing the old columns that were inside the Issue content type such as "Related issues", "issue status", etc, as follow:-

[image]

so my questions are why SP keeps the old columns and did not remove them once the issue content type were removed from the list?
second question, is it safe if i manually Delete these columns ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has always been the case, dating back to 2007 at least, and my assumption is to keep and data around. The fields can safely be removed if they are no longer in use.

Comment: Now since i have already defined a content type which i want to use, so is there a way to create a list inside SharePoint that does not have any content types or any columns.. so in this case i can add my custom content type to avoid any conflicts ?

Comment: Every list has a base content type associated with it. The cleanest you can get is to start from a custom list, add your content type, then remove the item content type. The only field is Title, which overlaps in yours so you'll be fine.

Comment: yes thi what i did i create a new custom list , remove the defualt content type, then remove the title column, finally i added my custom content type !!